# Basic ajax, trying to read local api file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am following the instruction from http://rest.learncode.academy/.

The code belows doesn't work with my localhost/api/friends file, but it works perfectly fine if I change the url to http://rest.learncode.academy/api/learncode/friends.

I checked the network under deverloper tool and it did GET the file and prints the console.log in console. However, they are not in the form of array, so when I try to append them, I got undefined

```
id: undefined, name: undefined, age: undefined


$(function(){

    var $friends = $('#friends');

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax/api/friends',
        success: function(friends){
            console.log('succuess', friends);
            $.each(friends, function(i, friend){
                $friends.append('<li>id: ' + friend.id + ', name: ' + friend.name +', age: ' + friend.age + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
```

This is what my api/friends file looks like

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}]
```

The console log prints

```
succuess [{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It works here too: http://jsfiddle.net/105ya6hj/ Try specifying `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` options. There's also the shorthand function `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: You are not specifying the `dataType` setting for the `$.ajax()` call. Try setting it to `'json'`. Without it, jQuery may not know to automatically parse the response, in which case the `friends` parameter value to the success callback is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jared Farrish and John S, I fixed the problem by adding dataType: 'json' in the $.ajax() call.